# Properly unwrap long text with Python

Tags: python, text

I'm trying to find a way to *properly* unwrap long text in Python. What I mean by "properly" is that only single occurrences of `\r\n` should be replaced by a space, and any sequence of two or more should be retained. For instance:

```py
text = "The 44th Chess Olympiad was an international\r\nteam chess event organised by the International Chess Federation (FIDE)\r\nin Chennai, India from 28 July to 10 August 2022.\r\n\r\nIt consisted of Open and Women's\r\ntournaments, as well as\r\nseveral events to promote chess.\r\n\r\nThe Olympiad was initially supposed to take place\r\nin Khanty-Mansiysk, Russia,\r\nthe host of the Chess World Cup 2019,\r\nin August 2020, but it was later moved to Moscow.\r\n\r\nHowever, it was postponed due to the COVID-19 pandemic\r\nand then relocated to Chennai."
```

`\r\n\r\n` should be retained, but `\r\n` should be replaced by a space.

I'm really bad with regular expressions, which is often the option with best performance, so any hint would be much appreciated!

Comment: Why do you think you need regular expressions for this? Also, did you search before asking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Python, you can have many other options not just using 're'. But if you wanna try, maybe you can try this one:

```
def unwrap_text(text):
    # Replace single occurrences of \r\n with a space
    unwrapped_text = re.sub(r'(?<!\r\n)\r\n', ' ', text)
    return unwrapped_text
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm sure there are. Often, though, regular expressions offer best performance. I'm open to other suggestions of course. Unfortunately, your proposal doesn't work as it only replaces any `\r` with a space, leaving `\n`.

Comment: Understand, following the same idea, it could be this one:
re.sub(r'(?<!\r\n)\r\n', ' ', text)

Comment: I have updated the answer, let's see if it works for you or not.

Comment: Yes, that's it, thanks! :-)